# Dual Bios complex Partition Setup

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, debian, multi-boot

I want to set up a dual bios system with Windows 10 Educational and Debian, but I struggle a bit deciding on the necessary / useful partitions especially as I am new to Linux in general and did read many different positions about partition sizes and if they are necessary at all etc.

So I thought of a shared partition among both operating systems, however I'm not sure if they should reference it as home - pointing to the same partition - or if another partition for exchange files should be used.

I will upgrade to an SSD with ~240GB and 1TB HDD disk space, here is what I thought of, although I do not want to say that all partitions and their sizes are necessary or good at all, it's just what I assembled researching different sources:

```
OS       use of partition    hdd/ssd    size in gb (x: whatever remains)

Windows  system              ssd        20
         page file           ssd?       8-32*
         home                hdd        250
         fast programs/games ssd        100+x
         slow     "          hdd        500+x

Debian   root                ssd        10-20**
         swap                hdd?       8-24***
         boot                ssd        1****
         home                hdd        100**

both     exchange            hdd        50
```

this would be quite a mess probably, <s>so combining both systems' home directories instead of a seperate exchange, would shorten it to the following:</s> (as Frank Thomas pointed out that may not be a good idea)

```
OS       use of partition    hdd/ssd    size in gb (x: whatever remains)

Windows  system              ssd        20
         page file           ssd?       8-32*
         fast programs/games ssd        100+x
         slow     "          hdd        500+x

Debian   root                ssd        10-20**
         swap                hdd?       8-24***
         boot                ssd        1****

both     home                hdd        400
```

Let's dive into a list of questions I still have (mind the asterisks):

1. **Do I store programs in Debian in root or home? (I would like to keep the programs on the hdd as ssd space is worth more, if I have seperate home directories, programs in debian's home would be way more comfy)
2. <s>Therefore is combining both home directories useful? (having debian programs I can fill a shared home directory with isn't exactly my goal, of course a different partition for the debian programs could be used if home is combined and programs aren't placed in root, but I don't see the point in "optimizing" the partitions by combining homes then)</s>
3. <s>Do page file and swap partition belong on an SSD or not? (found both positions, arguments about how long the ssd will live if it is constantly used due to that, however how does one define constantly here...)</s>
4. <s>*(Depends on 3.) As I have 16gb RAM, how much space should I reserve for the page file? (I did read all possiblities between 4 and 32gb, gotta be stingy with space if it is located on the SSD)</s>
5. **(Depending on 1.) How much place do I need in root? Found 10gb in debians system specs, but if I have to count in programs...
6. <s>***(Depends on 3.) Mostly similiar to 4., however more extreme as I found sources saying 1.5x RAM size...</s>
7. ****Do I need a boot partition for Debian at all? Do I need other boot partitions to realize dual bios at all?
8. Are there system recovery partitions I gotta mind here? Where would I rather place a Windows recovery partition?
9. How do I partition something like this at all? I did read about drives limited to 4 primary partitions, extended and virtual partitions and have no idea how some architecture like this has to be realized. Do I need third party boot loaders or something else?

Would love some help with this as I want to achieve a clear structure when I come to set up the OS' partitions.
Any response is appreciated.

Comment: Your linux and windows installs should not share partitions except for data content, and then only in a single-user scenario. Neither OS can reach their full potential for filesystem features using the others filesystem type. Pagefile and swap partition should both be on the SSD. your pagefile should be 24GB, but swap can be smaller. give yourself 15-20GB for /.

Comment: So you suggest that I should rather use the "exchange partition"-setup instead of merging home directories? I'm suprised pagefile should be bigger than swap. Thanks for pointing these things out.

Comment: I don't understand (1). It's not a clear question. Consider using LVM + MDRAID for Linux. Some form of software RAID for Windows would be sense too, IMO.

Comment: If your Debian requirements are unclear, I'd simply go for as simple as possible -- a single partition for everything. Maybe put it on LLVM if you want to be able to resize or scale later, but it might be easier actually to start over from scratch once you understand your needs better.